# How to communicate with a WCF Windows Service in VB6, without a dependency on .Net

Tags: wcf, web-services, vb6

We have an old application written by VB6 and now we have to add some features to it and we aim to do it with minimum changes to the application (as we are all .net developers) and make it able to communicate with a WCF webservice.

What is the best way to do so?

Thanks,

Comment: Which binding does the WCF service uses? I assume a .NET COM dll with the WCF client stuff in it is out of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your safest bet for interoperability is always going to be POX (or heck, even CSV) over HTTP.  Don't even bother getting entangled in REST let alone SOAP.

The only downside is you have to actually document your interfaces instead of just throwing WSDL out there, and you have to implement ad hoc security for services (at least those exposed to the Internet).  Of course you may be able to live with HTTP authentication if you require HTTPS.

Maybe see [Interoperability with POX Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738456.aspx) as a starting point.

You're throwing away 99% of what WCF otherwise does for you but considering most of that is a proprietary can of worms... no big loss.

POX over HTTP drastically reduces the burden on 3rd parties writing clients, as well as your own staff writing clients in house.  Just don't cheap out on versioning and graceful degradation any more than you would using SOAP.